# Как правильно проверить на соответствие строку с несколькими пропущенными словами?

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Есть набор шаблонов для текстов, вида "*Ваш заказ доступен по адресу: %w{1,3}. Забирайте скорее!*", где %w{1,3} — "набор слов, разделённый одним или несколькими пробелами". Под "словом" понимаем набор букв, цифр, и ряда спецсимволов. {1,3} — квантификатор, работающий аналогично квантификаторам в регулярках. Задача в том, чтобы научиться за минимальное определять тексты на соответствие подобным шаблонам. Было решено преобразовывать такие шаблоны в регулярные выражение. Таким образом, из приведённого выше примера получиться регулярка:

```
/^Ваш заказ доступен по адресу:\s(?:\s*[\w\d\,\.\!]+\s*){1,3}\.\sЗабирайте скорее!$/u
```

Естественно, такая регулярка может вызывать проблемы в виде catastrophic backtracking, но способа её оптимизировать я не вижу, с учётом того, что пробелов между словами может быть сколько угодно.
Буду благодарен за любые указания на мою слепость :)

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

Я вижу [один способ](https://regex101.com/r/iW2iA7/1) оптимизации: использовать сверхжадный захват (1) строки, включая обязательное завершение с последующей определением наличия этого самого завершения ретроспективной (4) проверкой. (O(66) против O(2441) на тестовой не подходящей строке и одинаковой сложности для подходящих) В примере помечены точки, обсуждаемые в тексте:

```
/Ваш заказ доступен по адресу:\s(?>\s*[\w\d\,\.\!]+\s*\.?){3,5}(?<=\.\sЗабирайте скорее!)$/
                                  ^1                   ^2  ^3   ^4
```

Но тут есть сложности с построением такого выражения из первичной строки. Во первых нам надо что бы вся "правильная" строка до самого конца могла быть захвачена набором символов, указанных в квадратных скобках. Во вторых, нам надо посчитать из скольких "слов" состоит часть строки, после применяемой маски. И увеличить на это кол-во слов квантификатор (3). Кроме того, в отличие от вашего варианта жадный захват считает отдельно стоящую точку (перед которой пробел) за отдельное слово, из за этого в конец захватываемого выражения, после пробела пришлось добавить возможность такой точки (2).

Собственно точка - это основной камень преткновения. Допустимость знака точка в середине слов (по вашему `abc.def` - это одно слово). Если бы она могла быть только в конце слов, то могли бы быть другие, менее жесткие варианты.

Ну и конечно, ваши регулярные выражения (вы не указали какой диалект у вас) должны поддерживать сверхжадный захват

**UPD** По [такому](https://regex101.com/r/iW2iA7/4) предложению [ReinRaus](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/481/reinraus):

```
/Ваш заказ доступен по адресу:(?:\s++(?:[\w\d,!]++|\.)*?){1,3}\s*+\.\sЗабирайте скорее!$/
```

Так гораздо проще для генерации ...

Comment: Да, точно. Проблема в точке, которая может быть частью "слова" и входит в обязательный текст в конце

Comment: @ReinRaus Ага, я ее долго пытался обойти ...

Comment: Вы обошли ее интересным способом, я бы сделал так: https://regex101.com/r/iW2iA7/4 , но это дает немного больше шагов.

Comment: @ReinRaus Шаги это не особо страшно, когда их не тысячи. Да, у вас гораздо проще для генерации

Comment: Большое спасибо @Mike за подробный ответ и @RainRaus за удобное для генерации выражение. Однако проблема в том, что каждая точка будет считаться как отдельное "слово" , а кто-нибудь  рано или поздно додумается сделать. например. так:  "Ваш заказ доступен по адресу: ул. Ленина, 6... Заберите его скорее!"
Т.к. скорость генерации регулярок некритична, скорее всего сделаем так:
Правило вида *Ваш заказ доступен по адресу: %w{1,3}. Забирайте скорее!* 
Будет преобразоваываться в рег. выражение: 
`/^Ваш заказ доступен по адресу:\s(?:[\w\d\,\.\!]+)(?:\s++[\w\d\,\.\!]+){1,3}\.\sЗабирайте скорее!$/u`

Comment: @AlexanderSadovnikov точки расположенные слитно считаются за одно слово так же они считаются за одно слово _вместе_ с тем, к чему стоят вплотную. Т.е. `6...` это одно слово. но вот никто не мешает мне написать `ул. Зои и Александра Космодемьянских д. 45/19 к. 1a стр. 2 (цокольный этаж)` вот и считайте теперь слова ...